# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS with htaccess and godaddy

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite

I'm new to the website, I've recently installed my SSL Certificate and the HTTPS Protocol on my website. At first, I tried to simply install the certificate by Control Panel of GoDaddy (MY Hoster) but I did not succeed in having good results. I have consulted this website finding different questions for the htaccess file, but after several tests the result is the same, do not work the HTTPS Protocol. This is my HTACCESS code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^ index \ .php $ - [L]
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -f
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_FILENAME}! -d
RewriteRule. /web/index.php [L]
SSLOptions + StrictRequire
SSLRequireSSL
SSLRequire% {HTTP_HOST} eq "www.ipsextant.eu"
ErrorDocument 403 https://www.ipsextant.eu/web/
</ IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

For one second I see the https protocol but while I navigate to the site the protocol I use is HTTP.

I have tried with different codes, the .htaccess file is in the main ROOT of the site.

Can i solve the problem ??

Are there any syntax errors in the code?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English

Bye Gianluca

Comment: It works for me. You're probably caching some now nonexistent redirect. Try opening up a private window in your browser and doing it again.

Answer (score 0):

Your website works fine for me, however, to force any page to be redirected to `https://`, here is 2 lines code for that!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And if you want to check it with PHP, you could do that,

```
    if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "on") { 
        $url = "https://". $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
        header("Location: $url");
      }
```

Your problem is the **cache**, delete your website's cache from your browser's settings/history and you will be good.

Good luck, Gianluca ;)

Answer (score 0):

How to force SSL with `.htaccess`:

You can force an HTTPS connection to your website by adding these rules in your website's `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```